# DRM Encoder Slave Driver

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, drm

I need to write a DRM encoder slave driver (to be used by a Xilinx board). I've looked at several encoder slave drivers that are in the Xilinx kernel repository but I'm still trying to wrap my head around what's needed. I'm struggling to find any documentation (not in source comments).

Are there any tutorials or good high level explanations of how one writes a DRM encoder slave driver?

---

So since tutorials are off-topic, but official documentation is not, is there any official documentation on DRM encoder slave drivers?